# I made a clock class in JavaScript, but it's not working properly when imported. I can only get the seconds and the interval doesn't seem to work too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class Clock extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){

    setInterval(() => (

      this.setState(
        { curHours :  new Date().getHours()}
      ),
      this.setState(
        { curMins :  new Date().getMinutes()}
      ),
      this.setState(
        { curSeconds :  new Date().getSeconds()}
      )
    ), 1000);
  }


state = {curHours:new Date().getHours()};
state = {curMins:new Date().getMinutes()};
state = {curSeconds:new Date().getSeconds()};

  renderHours() {
    return (
  <Text>{'Hours:'}{this.state.curHours}</Text>
    );
  }
  renderMinutes() {
    return (
  <Text>{'Minutes:'}{this.state.curMinutes}</Text>
    );
  }
  renderSeconds() {
    return (
  <Text>{'Seconds:'}{this.state.curSeconds}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

-I'm trying to make an app that can keep track of time kinda like a daily planner. So I need to get the current time in real time during app run time. The app is supposed to tell the user that they have failed to accomplish a certain task in a given time for example. I tried exporting the clock.js and using its functions but only the renderSeconds() is working, the others are only showing blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think functional components will be much simpler to solve this, but it's just my opinion.
Here's a link to an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sun-ypf1s?file=/src/Timer.js)

Comment: Is there a way where I can compare, say, the hours and minutes to another variable during app runtime? After being imported of course.

Comment: Absolutely. The hook will always have the latest data, so you can compare it in the render or in a side effect (useEffect). 
I updated the example with this:
````
      {time.getSeconds() > 30 && time.getSeconds() < 34 && (
        <div>HALF MINUTE</div>
      )}
````
Hope that's what you're looking for.

Also, @larz answer is correct for your Class component.

Answer (score 0):

When you're defining `state` three times, only the last one is persisted because you're overwriting the previous variable.  In addition, your initial state should be declared in a constructor.  Add this to the top of your class

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    curHours:new Date().getHours(),
    curMins:new Date().getMinutes(),
    curSeconds:new Date().getSeconds(),
  }
}
```